# What do British people think about female-only carriages on trains?

Tags: united-kingdom, public-opinion, discrimination, gender, transportation

I read that one politician in British Labour party suggested implementing a women-only carriage but immediately got backlash ([here](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2017/aug/23/shadow-minister-faces-backlash-over-women-only-train-carriage-idea) or [here](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2017/08/22/women-only-train-carriages-could-offer-safe-space-public-transport/)).

I tried accessing some of these articles but all of them seem to only cite statements by politicians and/or citizens, and don't include the detailed survey.

But I would rather like to know any public survey, if any, and how many citizens agree/disagree in what reasons. Has there been any such survey conducted, possibly in the past (since the idea was raised first in 2015)?

Comment: [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women-only_passenger_car#United_Kingdom), the idea was also raised in 1977 and 2014.

Comment: Note that many British trains have only two carriages. So a women-only carriage would be quite a big deal.

Comment: If we did polls for every single thing "one politician suggests" we'd never be able to hang up the phone.

Comment: @David Richerby "Note that many British trains have only two carriages. So a women-only carriage would be quite a big deal." and men would be forced into a more crowded area because women would not be prohibited from male's carriges (or would they?)

Comment: @Anixx Yes, it seems very likely that there would be women-only areas but no men-only areas so (regardless of the number of carriages), men would be forced to use more crowded areas of the train.

Comment: @DavidRicherby The proposal didn't include that level of detail. However, based on how it works in other countries, the "women only" carriage actually often allows some men with disabilities or of advanced age, and young boys. It's less of a "women only" carriage and more of a "less able to deal with the crush in the main carriage" car. The reason it is designated "women only" is to reduce the burden of having to set some kind of bar for admittance based on size, strength, age etc.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

A [YouGov poll](https://yougov.co.uk/opi/surveys/results#/survey/698fb3f3-87e7-11e7-a33b-07c60f426f61/question/89e1ef22-87e7-11e7-874f-fd53c18c1c15/gender) of 2948 people conducted in August 2017 gives:

> It has been suggested that trains should have women-only carriages. Which of the following comes closest to your view?
>
> - Good idea - women only carriages would provide a safe haven for women and will help combat the rise in sexual offences on public transport: 23%.
> - Bad idea - having women only carriages implies that the onus is on women to avoid harassment, rather than that men should not harrass them: 58%.
> - Don't know: 19%.

Comment: Nice find.  I wonder how many people think it's a bad idea for other reasons, and whether they picked *don't know,* or, despite disagreeing with the reason, *bad idea,* or if they just declined to respond to the survey.

Comment: Not a comment on your answer but the survey's question is loaded/leading. Something like "How much do you agree with women only carriage ? (Completely, a lot, a little, not at all)", would let you give your nuanced opinion without imposing on you two points that may not be the most relevents to answer the question.

Comment: @Jylo - was going to comment on that, myself.  I notice there's no option for "Reverse discrimination!!" which I'm sure would be an option that might describe pushback from unsympathetic males out there.

Comment: This is a spectacularly bad poll wording, as prior comments noted. For example, it excludes people who think it's a bad idea for OTHER reasons.

Comment: @user4012 I dislike the wording, but it doesn't exclude other reasons. The question asks "Which of the following _comes closest_ to your view?" (my emphasis). I'm sure one could come up with counterexamples but, in the great majority of real cases, anyone who thinks it's a good idea will feel closest to the first option and anyone who thinks it's a bad idea will feel closest to the second. Further, I doubt that either the pro- or anti- side would be more likely to get confused into answering "Don't know".

Comment: @DavidRicherby "Breaking news! 58% of survey respondents think a women's only carriage would put the onus on women to avoid harassment." Does this seem like an unlikely interpretation about the survey? What about people who didn't like it because of expected outrage if a male only carriage were suggested? Would they pick this choice? These choices are certainly not exhaustive given the likely interpretation of the results.

Comment: @Matt Once again, I suspect that people who think that it's a bad idea, _for whatever reason_ will fell that "Bad idea: blah blah blah" is the "closest to [their] view". And, yes, the media might misinterpret it but, honestly, they're much more likely to go for the simplistic "Breaking news! 58% of survey respondents think women-only carriages are a bad idea" than the much more nuanced version you give, even though your version is fed to them as a literal quote by the poll question.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Or they would just not answer the question, which possibly also skews the results.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian Which skews the results much worse.  At least if someone picks "Don't know", we see a hint as to how many of them there are (the 19% under "Don't know").

Comment: @David Richerby the second answer inplies that it is males who are guilty, this is a pure Feminist position. Actually it is a question, where women as a superior caste should be separated from males or should males be pressed and punished instead. Both answers are anti-male.

Comment: @Anixx Both answers presuppose that most sexual assaults and harassment against women on trains is committed by men. Are you suggesting that this isn't the case?

Comment: @DavidRicherby Even if we ignore the question of whether it is true that women are at a higher risk from men then from other women, there are several things that are wrong with this! Is male violence against males to be accepted? (If not, there should be "non-violent male carriages" to protect those...) - Are the females remaining in mixed carriages more likeley to become a victim? (Full segregation is to be enforced) - Are females never violent? (If they are sometimes, we need non-violent-female-carriages...)

Comment: @David Richerby You think males as a gender should be collectively punished and segregated? Why not then calculate probability of assaults based on race, religion, age and segregate people according these categories (remind you, this happenmmed in no-that-far past in America)?

Comment: @Anixx I am not supporting women-only carriages and I don't think I've said anything that could reasonably be interpreted as supporting them. I'm just trying to point out that the survey question isn't as bad as people claim it is.